# Keeping cached browser data inside ASP update panel textboxes/dropdowns for browser back click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, browser-cache

I'm new in VB.net/asp and am running a VB web application in a visual database program called IronSpeed designer. I'm primarily using IronSpeed in this case for its login/role security features.

I have a basic two page setup for this app. The user logs in then is taken to AccountEntry.aspx, they enter data into textboxes and select some dropdown values that are linked to a sql database, then they click "submit" to move to Results.aspx. On Results.aspx, the user can change data and then generate several types of reports (PDF, Excel, etc).

I'm used to setting up ASP controls inside ASPContent areas, and in these areas if a user performs a browser back click the previously entered data will still be on the page for potential user modification.

However in this web app, IronSpeed is setting up the page and asp controls inside an asp update panel. It appears inside an asp update panel, cached values can't be seen on a browser back click. In this case, it's important that the orginally entered values still be there for the user experience if the user advances to Results.aspx then clicks browser back to modify a value on AccountEntry.aspx.

If I have to I'll setup Session Variables and disable browser clicking, but that is last resort. Is there any way to save cached data inside an asp update panel and have it there for a browser back click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is creating a class, filling it with your form data and
store it in browser session.

```
Public Class Navigation
  Property Data1 as string
  Property Data2 as string
  Property ComboValue as string
  Property WhateverDesiredValue as string
End Class
```

Save the user data into the class and keep it in Session.

```
 Dim myNavitadionClass as new PreviousNavigation With { .Data1="" 'Assign values }
 Session("PreviousNavigation") = myNavitadionClass 
 'Submit the form.

 Then when you came again to the form you check the page_load event.

 If Not Session("PreviousNavigation") is Nothing Then
          Dim myClass as Navigation = Ctype(Session("PreviousNavigation"),Navigation)
 End If
```

And then you can fill the form exactly as it was.